# Angular, dynamic JSON import declaration in Typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, dynamic, import

I use the javascript command 'navigator.language' in app.components.ts to determine the language of the browser.

The corresponding JSON file should then be loaded.

In pure javascript I could do the following:

```
var userLang = navigator.language;
 
if (userLang == "en") {
   var lanFile = "/locale/" + userLang + ".json";
}
```

How can I do this in Angular?

The following code does not work, but shows what I would like to have:

```
var userLang = navigator.language;
import text_en from './json/' + userLang + '.json';
```

Anybody out there who have a workaround for me?

Comment: You can use the HttpClient and load them from the assets folder, so you'd do something like `HttpClient.get('assets/json/${userLang}.json')`

Comment: Interesting. I will try that. THX.

Comment: @Mikkel Christensen. Yes, This was the solution! Thx.